# How to completely bootstrap GHC & cabal from source

Tags: linux, haskell

I would like to install [pandoc](/questions/tagged/pandoc), but I have some restrictions due to the Corporate IT policies:

1. I cannot download any binaries.
2. Every executable has to be build from sources
3. Only Google Chrome have an access to internet (proxy restrictions)

So I downloaded `Pandoc` sources but it depends on [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell). Thus I downloaded `ghc-7.8.4-src.tar.bz2`

Unfortunately I discovered that I need `GHC` to build `GHC`. I downloaded `ghc-7.4.1-i386-unknown-linux.tar.bz2` and I got this error:

```
$ ./configure
checking for path to top of build tree... ./configure: line 2113: utils/ghc-pwd/dist-install/build/tmp/ghc-pwd: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
configure: error: cannot determine current directory
```

In `"/usr/src/ghc-7.4.1/utils/ghc-pwd/dist-install/build/tmp/usr/src/ghc-7.4.1/utils/ghc-pwd/dist-install/build/tmp"` I found a binary that should not be here. I cannot execute binaries.

I also discovered that I need [cabal](/questions/tagged/cabal) for which I need to install `Haskell` first.

It seems It's the snake that bites its own tail...

Is there a method that I can use to build Pandod, Haskell, Cabal and all the other dependencies?

Usually if I need a program, I just download the sources, execute `./configure`, solve the dependencies issues and eventually run `make install`. In this case it seems I need my whole lifetime just to understand what I need to build Pandoc...

Comment: Get a GHC binary and build or download a cabal binary - better yet the haskell platform, which comes with cabal - and install pandoc with `cabal install pandoc`.

Comment: Do you have a non-standard operating system that prevents you from using existing binaries, or your distribution’s packages?

Comment: In case you didn't know there is an web interface: http://pandoc.org/try/

Comment: I suppose this question might better be phrased “how to completely bootstrap GHC & cabal from source”. Once you have those, getting Pandoc is trivial...

Comment: To compile GHC, you need GHC. You appear to have a chicken-and-egg problem here...

Comment: Can you install GHC (or pandoc for that matter) through your package manager?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: it should certainly be possible to “upgrade” yourself through a whole lot of versions of GHC, as was historically done (the first ones were written in C, the first Haskell ones compiled with first-generation GHC, etc.). It would be a heck lot of work though – interesting question is, could there be an faster option.

Comment: Theoretically possible, but probably requires installing ancient versions of gcc and other tools first, so it still wouldn't solve OP's problem.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Isn't there an option to compile GHC to ANSI-C? (For porting?) That might be a shorter route to bootstrapping. You still need to install the binary for a C compiler though. ;-)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: interesting approach. Though IMO it would be somewhat pointless to allow compiler-generated C code... you could always transform any binary into “C code” that simply writes that executable (stored in the C code as e.g. Base64-string) back to a file, then executes it.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid [Porting](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/Porting) via .hc seems to be broken (the Bug is closed in favor of CrossCompilation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using the newly (beta-)released `stack` tool [[1](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/06/announcing-first-public-beta-stack)]

Recipe to download GHC and build pandoc:

1. Obtain the `stack` executable [[2](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/wiki/Downloads)]
2. Run:

   $ stack setup
3. Add the recommended directory to your PATH (will be something like `$HOME/.stack/progams/...arch.../ghc-7.8.4/bin`)
4. Run:

   $ stack install pandoc
5. Look for the `pandoc` executable in `$HOME/.local/bin`.

Links:

```
[1]: https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/06/announcing-first-public-beta-stack
[2]: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/wiki/Downloads
```

Comment: Nice try but it won't work. I can't download any executable. Thus, I can't do the first point `Obtain the stack executable`. I naively tried to download the version from GitHub but I get an error: `docker: Command not found`.

Comment: Exactly what did you do to get the  `docker: ...` error?

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I don't have an internet connection. I can only download things from Google Chrome. If `stack` is planning to fetch anything from the internet, it won't work.

Comment: Link #2 is an HTML page which tells you how to get the `stack` executable for various platform.

Comment: I cannot get any executable from internet. If I want to use `stack` I need to build it from the sources.

Comment: I would talk to your IT department about your problem. Obviously they don't require that you build `gcc` (or whatever C compiler you use) from source. If they don't allow `stack`, perhaps they will let you start with a "ghc bindist" which you can download [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_8_4#x86_64linux). The bindists are produced by the GHC compiler team so they are authoritative builds.

Comment: Most compilers are written in the same language they compile and GHC is no different. so building GHC "from source" is not a viable option for you. You're best bet is to get the powers that be bless a GHC bandits and from that you can bootstrap your way up. Or use a pandoc web service as @Sibi mentioned.